# Setting the jFrame title from Excel cells info

Tags: java, jframe, titlebar

I am totally new to Java and I am working on my assignment that requires to take create a jframe and name the title using the excel cells. Moreover, I do not know how to import the Excel data into my java as well. Thank you for the help. :)

```
public NewJFrame_1() {
    initComponents();
    Search.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle(getTitleFromDB());
// which i want to return with the excel cells' info
private String getTitleFromDB() {
    return "ABC Company";
```

Comment: `I do not know how to import the Excel data into my java as well.` - well you could ask your teacher since it is part of an assignment. Or you can search the web maybe keywords like: "import excel into java". The web is a great source of information, take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the excel file.

Check this [tutorial](http://java67.blogspot.pt/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html).